# Foregin key relationship error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have following model classes

Each Item has 4 languages in perticular languages table

```
public class Item
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime? ExpireDate { get; set; }

    }

public class ItemLanguage
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Language")]
        public int LanguageId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Item")]
        public int ItemId { get; set; }

        public Language Language { get; set; }
        public Item Item { get; set; }

    }
```

Each item library has 4 languages in perticular language table

```
public class ItemLibrary
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}")]
        public DateTime? ExpireDate { get; set; }

    }

public class ItemLibraryLanguage
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Language")]
        public int LanguageId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ItemLibrary")]
        public int ItemLibraryId { get; set; }

        public ItemLibrary ItemLibrary { get; set; }
        public Language Language { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I want to add items to the ItemLibraryItems table.
It need to save the ItemId and the ItemLibraryId in this table(Not the languageId). When displaying the selected items for the library it needs to show the according to the selected language in login.

```
public class ItemLibraryItem
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey("ItemLibrary")]
        public int ItemLibraryId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Item")]
        public int ItemId { get; set; }

        public ItemLibrary ItemLibrary { get; set; }

        public Item Item { get; set; }
    }
```

But when I'm trying to create the Controller by using ItemLibraryItem as the model class it gives the error
The entity types 'ItemLibraryItem' and 'ItemLibraryLanguage' cannot share table 'ItemLibraryLanguages' because they are not in the same type hierarchy or do not have a valid one to one foreign key relationship with matching primary keys between them.

Comment: Where is `ItemLibraryLanguages` entity? What kind of relationships you want to build (1:1, 1:n), then has the error occurred while scaffolding the model to create a controller class from them?

Comment: Relationship is 1:n with ItemLibrary and Items. ItemLibrary and ItemLibraryLanguage has 1:n relationship. same as Item and ItemLanguages has 1:n.
Error comes on scaffolding ItemLibraryItem model and creating the controller,

Comment: Try use `virtual` in your public `ItemLibrary` and `Item` at `public class ItemLibraryItem`